# Access JQuery Widget Option property from outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I access my JQuery UI Widgets `options` property? For example, how do I access the option `name` from the outside?

```
$.widget( "my.myWidget", {

    options: {
        name: "foo"
    },
});
```

The following doesn't work, also see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgzr7b7f/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var w = $('<p>abc</p>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .myWidget({name: "bar"});

    // How do I access the option/property 'name'?
    alert("Name=" + w.name);
    alert("Name=" + w.options.name);
    alert("Name=" + w.myWidget('name'));
});
```

Comment: it's under `w.prevObject["0"].jQuery31007758174325537992.myMyWidget.options.name` or `w.["0"].jQuery31007758174325537992.myMyWidget.options.name`, but i don't know if and where `jQuery31007758174325537992` is generated

Answer (score 1):

I have works a bit with the widget options and i see that you need to implement each methods for your new widget.

i have rewrite it in this way:

```
(function ($) {

$.widget( "my.myWidget", {

    options: {
            name: "foo"
        },
    value(){
        return this.options;
    },
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

  var w = $('p').myWidget({name: "bar"});

  alert("Name=" + w.myWidget("value").name);
});
```

where with `myWidget("value")` value is the name of the function declared in your widget.

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgzr7b7f/3/)